# python dataframe: display a sequence of events

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn, data-visualization

I have a dataset showing events and their time, and I'd like to visualize the sequence of the events.

for example: a plane took off from London on 1 oct 2020 10:00:00 and landed on Paris 1 oct 2020 15:00:00, then took off again from Paris on 1 oct 2020 17:00:00 and so on...

I'm working with python 3.7 and pandas, how to display this chain of events in a way that shows the sequence. any new packages are welcome
thank you in advance